# PSObject baseobject string in Exchange Online

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, exchange-server

I'm using C# and powershell to connect to microsoft online exchange services and gather the password expire date of my users.

Results I get after invoking powershell cmdlet Get-MSOnlineUser from C# (stored inside PSObject.Object or PSObject.ImmediateObject as a big string):

```
\n\rIdentity: test@test.com \n\r FirstName: TestFirstName \n\r LastName: TestLastName \n\r...etc.
```

I tried going through PSObject.Members or PSObject.Properties but no deal

My question would be - is there a way to deserialize those properties into one of PSObjects within powershell framework in .NET?

I think since all happens in the other side (microsoft exchange online side) so the remote won't send the complete hierarchy of classes so I cannot go down PSObject hierarchy...but not sure.

NOTE: I'm calling this command in migration console powershell but through C#:

```
> Get-MSOnlineUser -Identity test@test.com -Credential Get-Credential
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while microsoft team enabled the "password never expire" option. I don't need this anymore =)